# How to use count number of rows and print value in view file laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

app/http/controller/FirstController.php

```
public function delhi_property()
{
    $sql = DB::table('property')->where('city', 'Delhi')->orWhere('city', 'New Delhi')->get();
    return view('index',['results'=>$sql]);
}
```

resources/views/index.blade.php

```
<h3>({{ $results->count() }}) Properties</h3>
```

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/','FirstController@delhi_property');
```

I am new in laravel 5.4 Here, what am I doing I simply run a query as I mention above in my `Controller` and want to print numbers of rows in my view file but when I check it shows an error i.e.

`Undefined variable: result (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\real_estate\resources\views\index.blade.php)`

So how can I solve this problem? Please help me.

Comment: This error is somewhere else in your view. Please paste your complete view code.

Comment: As the errormessage states, the error is within the index.blade - you are trying to do something like `{{ $result->name }}` somewhere on something that isn't a property on that object.

Comment: let us see the fields in you database table which you are querying, you dont seems to have name there but you are requesting for name

Comment: I'm not familiar with the [DB Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries), but that syntax doesn't seems correct: [selects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#selects). `DB::table('property')->where('city', 'Delhi')->orWhere('city', 'New Delhi')->get()`

Comment: It seems you forget getting results from query set. Use ```->get()``` to get results after your ```select()``` then you can count results by ```count($results)```

Comment: I am doing some changes in my `controller query` and in my `view` file and it shows undefine variable result @ajafari

Comment: I have modified your function and posted the answer please check.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning the query result as "results", so in the view you need to access it as "$results". 
In the error it says undefined variable result. 
There is no "s" in it. 
So refer to the code line that error returns and check whether variable naming is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In controller:

```
public function delhi_property()
{
    $data = DB::table('property')->where('city', 'Delhi')->orWhere('city', 'New Delhi')->get();
    return view('index', compact('data'));
}
```

In blade file:

```
<h3>( {{ $data->count() }} ) Properties</h3>
```

OR

```
<h3>( {{  count($data) }} ) Properties</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

To count all rows in a query is a function for example:

```
count($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I am modifying your query a bit, will achieve the same result efficiently
    public function delhi_property()
    {
        $cityResults = DB::table('property')->whereIn('city', ['Delhi','New Delhi'])->get();
        return view('index',compact('cityResults'));
    }
```

In your view you can access the count as following:

```
<h3>{{ $cityResults->count() }} Properties</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using this to calculate and display the total count on a Bootstrap badge, try the following directly in the sidebar view:

```
<span class="badge badge-info right">{{ DB::table('property')->where('city', 'Delhi')->orWhere('city', 'New Delhi')->count() }}</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use larave's default function to count rows like example given below.

```
public function delhi_property()
{
    $result = DB::table('property')->where('city', 'Delhi')->orWhere('city', 'New Delhi')->get();
    $total_result = count($result);
    return view('index',compact(['result','total_result']));
}
```

In view you can print number of rows in variable $result.